# Caffe source code field "layer_param_.blobs_size()" cannot be found

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

When I read Caffe source file `Layer.hpp` I cannot find the code field `layer_param_.blobs_size()`, I will appreciate it if someone could tell me what this `layer_param_.blobs_size()` can be found.

Remarks: I haved looked up the source file `caffe-master\src\caffe\proto\caffe.proto` which define the code field `LayerParameter`, but I can't find the class `LayerParameter` member function `blobs_size()`;

source code :

```
template <typename Dtype>
class Layer {
 public:
  /**
   * You should not implement your own constructor. Any set up code should go
   * to SetUp(), where the dimensions of the bottom blobs are provided to the
   * layer.
   */
  explicit Layer(const LayerParameter& param)
    : layer_param_(param), is_shared_(false) {
      // Set phase and copy blobs (if there are any).
      phase_ = param.phase();
      if (layer_param_.blobs_size() > 0) {
        blobs_.resize(layer_param_.blobs_size());
        for (int i = 0; i < layer_param_.blobs_size(); ++i) {
          blobs_[i].reset(new Blob<Dtype>());
          blobs_[i]->FromProto(layer_param_.blobs(i));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It should be in `include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caffe layer loss\_weight\_size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892887/caffe-layer-loss-weight-size)

Comment: read the documentation of google protocol buffer: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#repeatednumeric

Comment: did you means that if I define a message struct of protocol,such as layerParameter ,the compiler will generate the blobs_size() about layerParameter field.

Comment: no no no ,is it the size() of blob filed?

Comment: // The blobs containing the numeric parameters of the layer.
  repeated BlobProto blobs = 7;  do you mean that blobs_size() is this field function that compiler generate?

Comment: Yes. `caffe.pb.h` is a C++ code generated from `caffe.proto` using protoc.